# Can I get the last error using IDA under Windows?

Tags: ida

There's a closed source binary that I'm analyzing, and there's a call to `VirtualProtect` that fails.

However, `VirtualProtect` stores the error code somewhere accesible only via `GetLastError`, and the binary doesn't even import that function.

Can I somehow get the error code without hooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) simply returns `LastErrorValue` from the [`TEB`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/nt%20objects/thread/teb.html) (`Thread Environment Block`) of the thread concerned.

You can access `TEB` of the current thread through the segment register `FS`.

`FS:[0x18]` contains the pointer to `TEB`.